# Gas fireplace is making a very loud popping noise about three times

Tags: fireplace

We had a gas leak repair done and the gas was shut off in the entire house to check all the lines last week.  Now there have been three times that our fireplace has made three very loud popping noises when it’s not even turned on!  Is there any correlation between the popping sounds and the gas being turned on and off?Would appreciate your input!

Comment: What does "very loud" mean? Can you offer a comparison?

Comment: It *could* be due to air in the line causing a pilot light to make the sound, but you'd be safer having the repairman fix the issue.

Comment: just to clarify, you heard 9 pops in total?

Comment: sounds like it could be an electric lighter, but i would describe that more like a click-click-click...